# Neon pothos plant needs to grow leaf again

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care

I have a neon pothos plant. First pic is its original state (IMG_1258), second pic is post-being bitten by a Beagle (IMG_6078)

Before
[image: pothos stem]

After
[image: pothos with new leaf]

I took it to a horticulturalist after it developed brown spots (I had left it in the sun) and the horticulturalist cut the leaf off. I contacted a plant doctor by email but I didn’t get much advice from them.

I was under the impression that it was infected - owing to the brown splotches, brown roots, and general detritus. However, from reading forums it seems like that’s just what happens when it’s left in water?

My question: I am wondering what I can do to get it from this state into being potted and growing leaves again.

I read that getting a water snail is a good idea? I’ve also noticed I can rub off the detritus, which is what I did with the two thin roots there (they were contained within the detritus). I am also considering using some fertiliser. As you can see, there is some growth on it - including a nub that I hope will turn into a leaf.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do anything other than provide light and change the water if if it gets cloudy.

I see a tiny bit of fungal activity on the leaf as evidenced by the tiny brown spots but the pothos can outgrow this.

If you are really keen to do something you can take a straight edge razor and cut the tip of the roots off which will promote branching and more roots.

Let it grow a good set of roots and then transplant to a soil less potting mix.

Do not:

- put rocks or stones at the bottom of the pot or top of the soil
- add anything else to the potting mix such as fertilizer

Do:

- provide good light
- water thoroughly and let dry out

Comment: Good answer. One more thing: Make sure the new growth faces up, not down. The top of the stem photo shows the bottom of the plant.